# tree structure with aggregated values on parent level

Tags: javascript, mongodb, tree, aggregate, data-modeling

I have read about the different models for storing tree-structured data and think that materialized paths or array of ancestors is the way to go in my case.

But I would need some conceptual guidance so that I don't start out in a way that proves to be wrong at a later stage

What I am aiming for is a structure like below with the aggregated values from subtrees present at the parent level. The blue dots represent departments and the figures below could represent department accounts.

Could this be done only with queries or do I need to code it?
Coming from a world of relational data...how should I model this? Is it two different collections, embedded documents or something else?

[image: Desired structure]